# Calculate the rate of change of a parameter, with given x and y coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, gradient

I have X and Y coordinates and a corresponding value for the parameter of the interest. I would like to get the rate of change of this parameter.

Here is the data excerpt:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|     X     |     Y      | Parameter |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 503830.38 | 4443799.09 |     12.78 |
| 503837.37 | 4443809.46 |     12.36 |
| 503840.75 |  4443792.1 |      9.48 |
| 503844.36 | 4443819.82 |     13.05 |
| 503847.74 | 4443802.47 |      8.95 |
| 503851.11 | 4443785.11 |      8.33 |
| 503851.35 | 4443830.18 |     13.84 |
| 503854.73 | 4443812.83 |      9.05 |
|  503858.1 | 4443795.48 |      8.27 |
| 503858.34 | 4443840.55 |     14.28 |
| 503861.47 | 4443778.12 |      5.27 |
| 503861.72 | 4443823.19 |      9.12 |
| 503865.09 | 4443805.84 |      8.22 |
| 503865.33 | 4443850.91 |     12.56 |
| 503868.46 | 4443788.49 |      5.32 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

I have tried numpy.gradient (`np.gradient(np.array(df))`) function and created a plot for the full dataset, but I couldn't really understand what are tuples produced. The explanation of the function states that it creates the gradient with regards to all axes and gives an example for 2D. However, what I want is to be able to specify the direction of interest. For example, considering that the data is in geographical coordinates, I would like to define the direction of the parameter rate of change in the S or SE direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not entirely trivial. You have a 2D function P=P(X,Y) defined in a number of points not on a coordinate grid, and you want to calculate dP/dX and dP/dY (which itself will depend on the points at which they are calculated) and, more generally, dP/d(direction) for any direction

So here is the simplest solution I can think of that hopefulyl sets you in the right direction. Basically the idea is to fit a linear function P ~ c1 X + c2 * Y and then c1,c2 can be interpreted as rate of change of P with respect to X and Y respectively

First we load the data and some imports

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

data = StringIO(
"""
X,Y,Parameter
503830.38,4443799.09,12.78
503837.37,4443809.46,12.36
503840.75, 4443792.1, 9.48
503844.36,4443819.82,13.05
503847.74,4443802.47, 8.95
503851.11,4443785.11, 8.33
503851.35,4443830.18,13.84
503854.73,4443812.83, 9.05
 503858.1,4443795.48, 8.27
503858.34,4443840.55,14.28
503861.47,4443778.12, 5.27
503861.72,4443823.19, 9.12
503865.09,4443805.84, 8.22
503865.33,4443850.91,12.56
503868.46,4443788.49, 5.32
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Then you ca visualize your data for inspection as such:

```
from matplotlib import cm
%matplotlib auto
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], df['Parameter'],cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

This will create a 3D plot that shows that actually the values of P (Parameter) is roughly linear in X,Y

Next we calculate linear regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
%matplotlib inline
lin_regr = Ridge(alpha=1e-4)
lin_res = lin_regr.fit(df[['X','Y']], df['Parameter'])
lin_fit = lin_regr.predict(df[['X','Y']])
plt.plot(lin_fit, df['Parameter'], 'o')
plt.plot(lin_fit, lin_fit, '-')
print(lin_res.coef_)
```

The plot shows the value of P versus our linear fit (blue dots) for visual confirmation that we are not way off:
[image: linfit]

The coefficient of linear regression are

```
[-0.15636806  0.11802771]
```

Therefore the rate of change of P in X direction is approx c1=-0.156 and in Y direction it is approx c2 = 0.118. For any other direction, with angle alpha say (in radians), it is given by

```
rate of change in direction alpha = c1*cos(alpha) + c2*sin(alpha)
```